# help with writing a sub query and assigning results to trigger a true or false result

Tags: oracle, subquery

Need some help on this query. So far I have it returning a count based on data from couple days previous.

What I am ultimately trying to do now is create a query that basically tells me if the count(*)=Xn value, then query is valid else no data set.

Its ok if I get no results.

Here's my query:

```
    SQL> select count(*) from in_source where to_date(year||'/'||month||'/'||day, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= trunc(sysdate) - 1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  500
```

So, basically if count(*)=500 then this query is 1 (false) or 0 (no results).  I'm thinking this would require a sub query?

Can someone help me tweak this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really understand what you are after, but hopefully one of these will work..

If you are trying to get if count(*) = 500 return a 1 else return a 0 then try this:

```
select case when count(*) = 500 then 1 else 0 end result
from in_source
where to_date(year||'/'||month||'/'||day, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= trunc(sysdate) - 1;
```

If you are trying to get if count(*) = 500 then return a 1 else don't return any rows try this:

```
select 1 result
from in_source
where to_date(year||'/'||month||'/'||day, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= trunc(sysdate) - 1
having count(*) = 500;
```

Comment: yes, you exactly what i was looking for. Never thought of using case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I give it a try:

```
select 1 from dual
  where 500=(select count(*) from in_source
               where to_date(year||'/'||month||'/'||day, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= trunc(sysdate) - 1);
```